# Tool to Execute SQL Server Scripts and Automatically Recognize and Prompt for Scripting Variables

Tags: sql-server-2016, deployment, source-control

I have a folder of scripts that contain multiple objects and jobs that I roll out every time I deploy a new SQL Server Instance. The scripts utilize scripting variables, as an example, here is an abridged example of a job creation script:

```
DECLARE @Owner SYSNAME = (SELECT [name] FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [sid] = 0x01)

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Myjob', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'blah', 
        @category_name=N'Database Maintenance', 
        @owner_login_name=@Owner, 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'$(AlertOperator)', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
```

Note that `@notify_email_operator_name` will be set to whatever value is passed to `$(AlertOperator)`

These scripts are usually run through a Powershell script which loops through the folder and passes values to the `$(AlertOperator)` variable.

This approach allows a suite of scripts to be kept which can be rolled out to a new server easily.

I was wondering if there was a GUI tool where I can open one or more .sql files and it would automatically recognize the scripting variables in those files and prompt for their values before running the files against one or more defined servers?

[This feature of SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/template-explorer?view=sql-server-ver15) Almost does what I want, the only problem is that the parameters must be in the `<parameter_name, data_type, default_value>` format rather than `$(variableName)` making it incompatible with the current Powershell setup. Another issue with it (which I could live with) is that it only really does a find and replace, rather than executing the script. I could live with that but the non support for `$()` is unfortunately a deal breaker

Comment: Im voting to close this as it is a shopping list question - in effect you're looking for which tool is right for this job, which isn't really suitable for this site.

Comment: I was more asking if such a thing exists to be honest

Comment: Yeah - that is a similar problem for the board. Such questions very quickly get out of date and are usually seen as unsuitable for the site.

Comment: FWIW I don't think anything like this exists that has wide adoption.

Comment: You might find this interesting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-undeclared-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is set up your scripts as templates in SQL Server Management Studio and then use the replace template parameters feature -see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/template-explorer?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is 95% there, the only problem is it doesn't support variables in the $(variable) syntax. The only other issue is it basically does a find and replace on the text so effectively changes the script (I could live with this bit, but the $() issue is a deal breaker)

Comment: Can't you search and replace $(variable) with <parameter_name, data_type, default_value>

Comment: I could but that is getting more and more manual to the point where it would be easier to just type the literal values required in the script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what degree of flexibility it'll provide for your specific problem but I've seen [dbatools](https://dbatools.io) recommended for similar things. I've personally haven't had the chance to try them but plan to when I get some time. It's goal is to simplify common repetitive tasks such as deployments across multiple servers and integrates with Powershell somehow, so might be worth checking out.